# Unknow Heroku crash error -- succesfully deployed but cannot open

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

It is strange that 'Your app was successfully deployed.' was shown in Heroku dashboard but when clicking the 'View', it shows Application Error -->"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command". When I check the log in terminal, it shows below. I have attached requirements.txt in my github project. Anyone knows?

My github link: https://github.com/Zakk-Yang/heroku_test

```
2020-05-02T19:33:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/d509e851-0e0a-4c4f-b46f-c69ca1f19771/activity/builds/870305ce-1f94-4e25-8838-d3a2d3bde11b
2020-05-02T19:44:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T19:44:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/d509e851-0e0a-4c4f-b46f-c69ca1f19771/activity/builds/7062835b-3c28-4d1e-894a-1ec232acee70
2020-05-02T19:46:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T19:46:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/d509e851-0e0a-4c4f-b46f-c69ca1f19771/activity/builds/cbdac05d-8e51-4e6d-9c3e-89c1f9914e24
2020-05-02T19:48:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T19:48:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/d509e851-0e0a-4c4f-b46f-c69ca1f19771/activity/builds/20d4b356-b440-4303-bb00-bb999388dad8
2020-05-02T19:53:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T19:56:33.476313+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T19:56:33.476313+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3040a827 by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T19:57:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-02T19:58:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:00:45.417122+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3040a827 by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:00:45.417122+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:01:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-02T20:04:33.506371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=96e76633-7a47-4284-9f12-bb6588b76178 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:04:34.059409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=83cd8e9f-6ad6-4146-afb8-520a3fa15db5 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:06:16.900305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=fdda66dc-5892-42bf-b033-f80b2bef38c9 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:06:17.311733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=d24e7e75-8f31-49a3-9624-5c12eac58da1 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:12:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:15:26.554818+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dcd7dbdf by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:15:26.554818+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:15:26.575162+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:15:51.389986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-02T20:15:51.463093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-02T20:15:51.325104+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-05-02T20:16:14.941058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-02T20:16:14.870393+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-05-02T20:16:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-02T20:17:01.383913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=4eb4138e-1d97-4e47-8945-eb7e8d84f5e3 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:17:01.722305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=d64b4d30-6825-4239-b5d6-c3baf30dcc24 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:31:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:34:29.210909+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:34:29.210909+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dcd7dbdf by user abc@hotmail.com
2020-05-02T20:34:30.707372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-02T20:34:53.655713+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-02T20:34:53.728793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-02T20:34:53.599642+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-05-02T20:35:16.967890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-02T20:35:16.905180+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-05-02T20:35:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-02T20:37:00.519288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=b1d5afd4-0cf2-46f2-9491-6a6e0dee3001 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:37:00.870318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=e6e47cdd-a998-42a8-b6dd-71b1cee8b6ec fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:38:35.332641+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=0cd8ab72-44ce-41af-a8a8-338d94e6b3b6 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:38:35.558510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=c6cd780c-f311-44ee-b1d2-fd41d2460d72 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T20:57:20.114157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-02T20:57:45.023096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-02T20:57:44.955558+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-05-02T21:15:25.725995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=c8d33f04-8e24-4597-89aa-283b5d745bbb fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T21:15:26.194574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=covid19streamlitdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=e4c5c594-5840-4a10-a1fd-99e907021d45 fwd="195.166.219.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-02T21:32:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abc@hotmail.com
```

Comment: You need a Procfile

Comment: Hello, I have added both setup.sh and Procfile. But the situation still occurs.......

Comment: sorry problem solved, for other people's convenience, I put the tutorial link here: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-deploy-a-streamlit-app-with-heroku-5f76a809ec2e